# How can i make a thread which gets my current location every 5 minutes in my ios app?

Tags: ios, multithreading, sample

If anyone has any similar project and could share it i would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Please read the FAQ - we're not going to do your job for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd start with an NSTimer Object. Do Research on it. IN particular there's a parameter that specifies duration float and repeats boolean.  Then do some reasearch on the built in Libraries and Frameworks that uses your iPhone Location Services. From there you can get the coordinates, Long and Latitude. There is also a sample project on Apple's Developers site that has Location Services detailed in a dummy down project sample.

Also you can take the long and lat and send it into GEO Services provided by Google Maps, and Locations APIs that will reverse lookup your long/lat into ZIP, City, Street Address Burrough, etc, etc. Please do some research and hopefully this will point you in the right direction(s).